# Accessing nested JSON elements in Perl

Tags: json, perl

I get an error when attempting to access the contents of my JSON array.

Here is the contents of my JSON array assets.json:

```
[{"id":1002,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"172.16.77.239"}]}]},{"id":1003,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.2"}]}]}]
```

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use File::Slurp;

my $json_source = "assets.json";   

my $json = read_file( $json_source ) ;
my $json_array = decode_json $json;

foreach my $item( @$json_array ) { 
    print $item->{id};
        print "\n";
    print $item->{interfaces}->{ip_addresses}->{value};
        print "\n\n";
}
```

I get the expected output for $item->{id} but when accessing the nested element
I get the error "Not a HASH reference"

Comment: try printing it with `Data::Dumper` to see what your `perl` datastruture looks like.

Comment: `$item->{interfaces}[0]{ip_addresses}[0]{value}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Data::Dumper` is your friend here:

Trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;


my $json_array = decode_json ( do { local $/; <DATA> } );
print Dumper $json_array;

__DATA__
[{"id":1002,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"172.16.77.239"}]}]},{"id":1003,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.2"}]}]}]
```

Gives:

```
[
  {
    'interfaces' => [
      {
        'ip_addresses' => [
          {
            'value' => '172.16.77.239'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    'id' => 1002
  },
  {
    'interfaces' => [
      {
        'ip_addresses' => [
          {
            'value' => '192.168.0.2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    'id' => 1003
  }
]
```

Important point of note - you have nested arrays (the `[]` denotes array, the `{}` a hash).

So you can extract your thing with:

```
print $item->{interfaces}->[0]->{ip_addresses}->[0]->{value};
```

Or as [friedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20745/friedo) notes:

> Note that you may omit the -> operator after the first one, so `$item->{interfaces}[0]{ip_addresses}[0]{value}` will also work.

Comment: Sobrique, thank you for your fast help as always, helping my learning.

Comment: I've set the `Data::Dumper` options so that the output is a bit less sprawling. Please revert my edit if you wish

Comment: Note that you may omit the `->` operator after the first one, so `$item->{interfaces}[0]{ip_addresses}[0]{value}` will also work.