# Perl variable becoming undefined in loop

Tags: json, perl, csv

**Edit: modified code and output to make it more clear**

**Edit 2: Added example input for reproduction**

I have a JSON file and a CSV file and I am running comparisons on the two. The problem is that $asset_ip is correctly defined in the outer foreach loop, but when in the nested loop $asset_ip becomes undefined.

Why is $asset_ip becoming undefined?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# perl -e'use CPAN; install "Text::CSV"'
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;
use File::Slurp;
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => ',' } );

my $csv_source  = "servers.csv";
my $json_source = "assets.json";
my $dest = "servers_for_upload.csv";

# defined these here as I need to use them in foreach loop and if statement:
my $csv_ip;
my @fields;
open( my $csv_fh, '<', $csv_source ) or die "$! error trying to read";
open( my $dest_fh, '>', $dest ) or die "$! error trying to read";

my $json = read_file($json_source);
my $json_array = decode_json $json;

foreach my $item (@$json_array) {
    my $id = $item->{id};
    my $asset_ip = $item->{interfaces}->[0]->{ip_addresses}->[0]->{value};

    # test the data is there:
    if ( defined $asset_ip ) {
        print "id: " . $id . "\nip: " . $asset_ip . "\n";
    }

    while (my $line = <$csv_fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $csv->parse($line) ) {
            @fields = $csv->fields();
            $csv_ip = $fields[0];
        }
        else {
            warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
        }

            if ( $csv_ip eq $asset_ip ) {
                # preppend id to csv array and write these lines to new file
                unshift( @fields, $id );
                print $dest_fh join( ", ", @fields );    
        }
    }
}
close $csv_fh;
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $asset_ip in string eq at script.pl line 43, <$csv_fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $asset_ip in string eq at script.pl line 43, <$csv_fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $asset_ip in string eq at script.pl line 43, <$csv_fh> line 3. 
id: 1003
ip: 192.168.0.2
id: 1004
ip: 192.168.0.3
id: 1005
ip: 192.168.0.4
```

assets.json:

```
[{"id":1001,"interfaces":[]},{"id":1003,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.2"}]}]},{"id":1004,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.3"}]}]},{"id":1005,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.4"}]}]}]
```

Note, that for the first iteration, $asset_ip **will** be undefined. I will therefore alter the code to only run the eq comparison if $asset_ip is defined. However, for this example I am not doing the check because all iterations are undefined.

servers.csv:

```
192.168.0.3,Brian,Germany
192.168.0.4,Billy,UK
192.168.0.5,Ben,UK
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should have double quotes, not single quotes, in `die '$! error trying to read'`.  As is, you will get `$!` instead of the value of the variable if those errors happen.

Comment: Sorry - didn't mention - I get errors that $asset_ip is undefined when I run the script.

Comment: Quoting the error message (and line number) helps diagnose. As does some sample source data. Presumably this is the JSON you're using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737301/accessing-nested-json-elements-in-perl Do you have some sample CSV data?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to include sample data. Simply put, $asset_ip is defined as an ip address in the outer loop, but once in the inner loop it is undefined. The second loop iterates the correct number of times for the number of lines in the CSV file.

Comment: Without the sample data, we can't reproduce the problem, and thus are left guessing as to which line is causing it, and how. That's why we usually request a [mcve] - there's no clear reason why it's becoming undefined or _where_ it's becoming undefined.  But there is a clear logic error around reading/re-reading `$csv_fh`.

Comment: Be aware - you're potentially recycling `@fields` if the line doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: The edit has improved matters. The only way I can think of why that _might_ he happening is down to your JSON. Is there any chance your JSON has more than 3 elements in top level array?

Comment: My JSON will only ever be like in my second edit, no more than 3 elements.

Comment: Lovely. With that data I can reproduce the error. Bear with me.

Comment: @Jamie - ok - found your problem. It's this: `[{"id":1001,"interfaces":[]},` - id `1001` doesn't have any interfaces, so `$asset_ip` _is_ undefined.

Comment: Sobrique, that is correct, it is undefined in that instance. 

If I surround my last if statement with if (defined $asset_ip) { }, the result is nothing is output. I would expect that the test would skip the line with no interfaces, and continue as normal to the other lines?
Edit: didn't see your answer edit, will go through that now, thanks.

Comment: It does, but you've already read `$csv_fh` to the end of file, so the loop doesn't execute at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem will be this:

```
foreach my $line (<$csv_fh>) {
```

You execute this within our outer loop. But when you do this, your `$csv_fh` ends up at the end of file.

Once you have done this, subsequent iterations of your *outer* loop will not execute this inner loop, because there's nothing left for it to read from `$csv_fh`.

An easy test if this is your problem is to add a `seek` e.g. `seek ( $csv_fh, 0, 0 );`.

But this isn't an efficient thing to do, because then you'll be looping through the file multiple times - you should instead read it into a data structure and use that.

Edit: Here is your problem:

```
[{"id":1001,"interfaces":[]},{"id":1003,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.2"}]}]},{"id":1004,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.3"}]}]},{"id":1005,"interfaces":[{"ip_addresses":[{"value":"192.168.0.4"}]}]}]
```

And specifically:

```
[{"id":1001,"interfaces":[]}
```

Your *first* element in that array doesn't have a `$asset_ip` defined.

This means - on your first pass - `$asset_ip` is undefined and generates the errors. (no line is printed because of your `if defined` test).

But then - the code proceeds to traverse `$csv_fh` - reading to the end of file - looking for matches (and fails 3 times, generating 3 error messages.

Second iteration - for id `1002` - the IP isn't in the file anyway, but `$csv_fh` has already been read to end-of-file (EOF) - so that `foreach` loop doesn't execute at all.

This can be made *workable* by:

- adding `else next;` after that `if defined`.
- adding `seek` to after the while loop.

But really - a rewrite would be in order so you're not re-reading a file over and over anyway.

Very crudely:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# perl -e'use CPAN; install "Text::CSV"'
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;
use File::Slurp;
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => ',' } );

my $csv_source  = "servers.csv";
my $json_source = "assets.json";
my $dest        = "servers_for_upload.csv";

# defined these here as I need to use them in foreach loop and if statement:
my $csv_ip;
my @fields;
open( my $csv_fh,  '<', $csv_source ) or die "$! error trying to read";
open( my $dest_fh, '>', $dest )       or die "$! error trying to read";

my $json       = read_file($json_source);
my $json_array = decode_json $json;

foreach my $item (@$json_array) {
    my $id       = $item->{id};
    my $asset_ip = $item->{interfaces}->[0]->{ip_addresses}->[0]->{value};

    # test the data is there:
    if ( defined $asset_ip ) {
        print "id: " . $id . "\nip: " . $asset_ip . "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "asset_ip undefined for id $id\n";
        next;
    }

    while ( my $line = <$csv_fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $csv->parse($line) ) {
            @fields = $csv->fields();
            $csv_ip = $fields[0];
        }
        else {
            warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
        }

        if ( $csv_ip eq $asset_ip ) {

            # preppend id to csv array and write these lines to new file
            unshift( @fields, $id );
            print {$dest_fh} join( ", ", @fields ),"\n";
        }
    }
    seek( $csv_fh, 0, 0 );
}
close $csv_fh;
```

I would suggest this also needs:

- change of while so you're not re-reading the file each time
- You're using `Text::CSV` so using a `print join ( ","...` doesn't seem a consistent choice. If your data warrants `Text::CSV` it's worth keeping it for output too.

Comment: I was just writing a witty comment in the _edit summary_... :(

Comment: I'll just imagine something hilarious and insightful.

Comment: In general, *if* you have to iterate over the contents of a file multiple times anyway, re-reading the file may not really be such a bad idea, since the OS will cache the data anyway. But in this case, of course, much more efficient single-pass algorithms exist.

Comment: Excellent description

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: the OS may cache the contents, and probably Perl's own I/O layer will do some buffering, but with enough data in the file, you'll see repeated read() system calls, resulting in unnecessary kernel context switches... Sorry for the nitpicking. ;-)

Comment: @Steven: Well, I started it. ;-) And you're right that re-reading the file is most likely not the most efficient method. I'm just saying that it may not be *quite* as bad as one might first assume, since the later passes over the file will likely be (potentially much) faster than the first, if the file is small enough to fit in the disk cache. And it does have the advantage that, if the file is *not* small enough to fit in memory, reading it several times from disk is quite likely to be faster than trying to slurp it all at once and being forced to swap as a consequence.